# PHP mySQL one-to-many vs many-to-many

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, many-to-many, one-to-many

I have a pet project I am working on that is a social concept. The concept at hand is the tables to support the data then query them. For this notion I am just wanting to start simple and build my way up. The theory is like any other social site. Just a comment-esk system with 1-nth number of people sharing with specific people of their choice. I understand the concept but can't wrap my head around the logic yet maybe its because I haven't found a note worthy article yet and/or example there of for that matter.

So that said I have come to respect the wealth of knowledge people have to offer from this site and am asking for help on getting started. What would the tables look like along with corresponding queries to start building up the concept I am looking to do.

Comment: Looking for examples.. not full solutions, but something to actually get me started, as I've done plenty of reading but still can't figure out how to actually start the ball rolling at the moment. Thanks for the vote down though..

Comment: suggest you read the faq on what is and is not a good SO question.

Comment: @chris: I didn't downvote.  But this is not a real question, so I voted to close.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An interesting place to start could be looking into the term "many-to-many". While a commonly used term, it isn't usually as simple as a one-to-many. While it is a perfectly fine way to describe a relationship, it's not so much in SQL terms as it isn't possible. A simple way around this is having three tables, two to hold the things in the relationship and one table to connect them.

An interesting read here possibly: http://www.tonymarston.net/php-mysql/many-to-many.html

Comment: This is very much along the lines of what I seek. Would you possibly be able to provide a good means of storing comments, based on this notion from the link I would think the X table would be a table storing friend associations what tables a,b would be the post/comment relation or something to the effect there of. Im still trying to sort in my head how to handle what I want to do, but this article definitely helped, thanks